# Use of allow-return-values at test tag level

Tags: java, testng

I am trying to use `allow-return-value = "true"` at test level. When I run the code the method with return type as non-void is still ignored where as I expect it to be called because of the allow-return-value set to true explicitly. This completely works fine when I do it at Suite level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Retrun value True" >
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" allow-return-values="true" name="TestNGExperiment">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestNGExperiment"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

public class TestNGExperiment {

@Test(testName = "divide4by2")// the method with a return type
public int divide4by2() {
    System.out.println("divide4by2 called");
    return 4/2;
}

@Test(testName = "printHello")
public void printHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

Actual result:

> Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Expected result as per me:

> Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Comment: In documentation stated can use at <Test> but actually working at <Suite>

Comment: Just want to understand that what is the use case for returning a value from a test case, because ideally test case should not have a return type. Asking this because then i would be able to help you better.